# How can I improve maxCacheMB and maxMergeSizeMB in the solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr

System parameters：

```
 maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0
```

I want to change the maxCacheMB and maxMergeSizeMB like below:

```
maxCacheMB=64.0 maxMergeSizeMB=12.0
```

I can't find the results from the Internet and official website

my solrconfig.xml

```
 <directoryFactory 
name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to the source](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/1d85cd783863f75cea133fb9c452302214165a4d/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/core/NRTCachingDirectoryFactory.java#L39) the NRTCachingDirectoryFactory supports both parameters given in the factory definition:

```
maxMergeSizeMB = params.getDouble("maxMergeSizeMB", DEFAULT_MAX_MERGE_SIZE_MB);
maxCachedMB = params.getDouble("maxCachedMB", DEFAULT_MAX_CACHED_MB);
```

Arguments to the directoryFactory is given under the element:

```
<directoryFactory ...>
    <int name="maxMergeSizeMB">12</int>
    <int name="maxCachedMB">64</int>
</directoryFactory>
```